# SQL Server: when Else is case it is showing 0 as default in CASE clause

Tags: sql-server

This query is run on AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail table.

My query: in the CASE clause I have clearly stated to show - when it is the ELSE case. This query removes the repeating SalesOrderID and after 1st time shown it should be replaced with "-" this character.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesOrderID ORDER BY SalesOrderID ASC) = 1 THEN SalesOrderID ELSE '-' END  AS SalesOrderID,
    R.ProductID,
    R.OrderQty,
    R.UnitPrice,
    R.LineTotal

FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS R
```

currently showing 0 even though i said in the ELSE to show me -

[image]

Comment: That's because you're converting '-' to a number here. You need to convert `SalesOrderID` to a string to see the - (or do something to similar effect). As it currently stands, since salesorderid is an integer and ints have higher precedence than strings, the case expression tries to convert '-' to an integer, which is just 0.

Comment: `CASE` statement can only return a single data type. In your case, since you wanted a `dash` so you need to convert `SalesOrderID` to string

Comment: It is because the datatype of SalesOrderId is int. See my answer. Here is the link of table https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc//browse-sql-doc/TestServer/User_databases/AdventureWorks2012/Tables/SalesOrderDetail.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query will solve your issue

```
 SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesOrderID ORDER BY SalesOrderID ASC) = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),SalesOrderID) ELSE '-' END  AS SalesOrderID,
        R.ProductID,
        R.OrderQty,
        R.UnitPrice,
        R.LineTotal

    FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS R
```

Comment: @Zabi: I think your answer is this right or you want something else?

Comment: it should be converted after ELSE but still if I convert it there, I am losing the opportunity to define my input and CONVERT doesnt allow default values to be defined. So, i used subquery in FROM clause to convert the SalesOrderID to resolve this problem.

Comment: OK, but as per your need and output, I have created a query.

Comment: damn, sorry it actually works, marked it as an answer

Comment: @ZabiSidiqkhil: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your are getting 0 because data type of `SalesOrderId` is `int`. If it will be `varchar` then it will come `-`. Try this below query.

```
Create table Orders (SalesOrderId Varchar(5), ProductId int, OrderQty int, UnitPrice decimal,
LineTotal decimal)

insert into Orders
values
(43659, 776, 1, 2024.94, 2024.99),
(43659, 777, 3, 2024.94, 2024.99),
(43659, 778, 1, 2024.94, 2024.99)

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesOrderID ORDER BY SalesOrderID ASC) = '1' 
        THEN SalesOrderID 
    ELSE '-' END  AS SalesOrderID,
    R.ProductID,
    R.OrderQty,
    R.UnitPrice,
    R.LineTotal

FROM Orders AS R
```

You can find the live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/AMLQA12822) in both format of datatype `int` and `varchar`.

Without changing datatype you can achieve it using query as shown below

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesOrderID ORDER BY SalesOrderID ASC) = '1'  
        THEN Convert(Varchar(5), SalesOrderID)
    ELSE '-' END  AS SalesOrderID,
    R.ProductID,
    R.OrderQty,
    R.UnitPrice,
    R.LineTotal
FROM OrdersInt AS R
```

Comment: It's datatype is as shown in the link https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc//browse-sql-doc/TestServer/User_databases/AdventureWorks2012/Tables/SalesOrderDetail.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input i made it work

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY R.SalesOrderID ORDER BY SalesOrderID ASC) = 1 THEN SalesOrderID 
        ELSE ' ' END AS SO_ID,
        R.ProductID,
        R.OrderQty,
        R.UnitPrice,
        R.LineTotal

FROM(SELECT 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),S.SalesOrderID) AS SalesOrderID,
        S.ProductID,
        S.OrderQty,
        S.UnitPrice,
        S.LineTotal
    FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS S) AS R
```

Sample data

[image]